# silverlight datagrid celleditended

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

In celledit ended I want to fire method only if the values changed

I have certain editable columns I want to fire the method only if the value already changed

the DataGridCellEditEndedEventArgs the property `e.EditAction` always return comitted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to the [DataGrid.PreparingCellForEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.preparingcellforedit%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) event (or maybe [DataGrid.BeginningEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.beginningedit%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) but I'm not 100% positive) and store the cell's value at that point.

Then instead of listening to `DataGrid.CellEditEnded`, listen instead to [DataGrid.CellEditEnding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.celleditending%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). This event is specifically designed to give you an option to cancel the editing so it's not treated as a commit. The [DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcelleditendingeventargs%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for it provides a [Cancel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs.cancel%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) `bool` property. Check if the new value is the same as the old value, and if it is, set the the `Cancel` property to `true`. Then when the `CellEditEnded` event fires, its `EditAction` will be `Cancel`.

```
void MyGrid_PreparingCellForEdit(object sender, DataGridPreparingCellForEditEventArgs args)
{
    //store current value
}

void MyGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs args)
{
    //check if values are the same
    if (valuesAreSame)
        args.Cancel = true;
}
```